Generated .d.ts file is empty
I'm trying to make a react ui library with typescript but when trying to generate .d.ts file it's just empty with export { }.
my project structure:
lib/
   components/
     Button.tsx, etc...
   index.ts
src/ For importing the components and testing them

This is my vite config:
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'lib/index.ts'),
      name: 'VeilUI',
      fileName: 'veil-ui',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [dts({ outDir: 'dist', insertTypesEntry: true })],
});

This is index.ts :
  export { Accordion, AccordionItem } from './components/Accordion';
  export { Button } from './components/Button';
  export { Select, SelectItem, SelectSeparator } from './components/Select';
  export { Tooltip } from './components/Tooltip';

tsconfig.js:
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.app.json" }, { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

tsconfig.app.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["lib"]
}

tsconfig.node.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["ES2023"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

package.json :
"main": "./dist/veil-ui.umd.cjs",
  "module": "./dist/veil-ui.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/veil-ui.js",
      "require": "./dist/veil-ui.umd.cjs"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc && vite build"
  },

I have watched countless tutorials on how to use vites library mode, building the actual components is working but trying to create .d.ts file is impossible for some reason. One time i have acctually got it to work but uppon publishing to npm i have discovered that the whole thing is totally broken and there wasn't even basic prop autocompletion.
